# OpenEdge ABL reserved keyword as temp-table field name (inferred from JSON data)

Tags: json, openedge, progress-4gl

I am stuck with the following situation:

My method receives a response from external REST API call.  The JSON response structure is as below:

```
{
"members": [
    {
        "email_address": "random@address.org",
        "status": "randomstatus"
    },
    ...etc... 
]}
```

I am reading this to temp-table with READ-JSON (Inferring ABL schema from JSON data) and try to process the temp-table. And this is where I am stuck: 
when I am trying to put together a query that contains temp-table field *"status"*, the error is raised.
Example:

```
hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE('FOR EACH ' + httSubscriber:NAME + ' WHERE ' + hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD(iStatus):NAME + ' = "randomstatus"').
```

gives:

> **Unable to understand after -- "members WHERE".(247)

I have tried referencing directly by name as well,  same result.

Probably the *"status"* is a reserved keyword in ABL. Might that be the case? And how can I get over this issue to reference that *"status"* field?

Unfortunately the format and key names of JSON response are not under my control and I have to work with that.

Comment: Are you sure your buffer values are correct? I'm not getting that error when I have "status" in a dynamic query. It could be that httSubscriber:NAME and/or hBuffer:FIELD-VALUE(iStatus):NAME are not returning the values you think they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SERIALIZE-NAME` in the temp-table definition to internally rename the field in question. Then you would have to refer to the field with another name but in it's serialized form it would still be known as `status`.

Here's an example where the `status`-field is renamed to `exampleStatus`.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttExample NO-UNDO
    FIELD exampleStatus AS CHARACTER SERIALIZE-NAME "status".

/* Code to read json goes here... */

/* Access the field */
FOR EACH ttExample:
    DISPLAY ttExample.exampleStatus.
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been known to do silly things like this:

```
JSONData = replace( JSONData, '"status":', '"xstatus":' ).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the temp-table (hard-coded or via string appending) + '.' + hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD(iStatus):NAME (...)

It should help the compiler understand you're talking about the field. Since it's not restricted, this should force its hand and allow you to query.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work in my case. `(...) httSubscriber:NAME + '.' + hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD(iStatus):NAME (...)` which evaluates to `members.status`, gives the same error.